# Unable to open XLSX file using Apache POI: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm having problems trying to open an XLSX file with Apache POI.

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/my/file.xlsx"))) {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(f); // This is the line throwing the exception
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

    }
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
    at my.TEST.ExcelTest.main(ExcelTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Background:

- Running JDK 7 on MacOS X (Mavericks)
- Using NetBeans
- Imported jars (all from Apache POI binary distribution):

  - `poi-3.11-20141221.jar`
  - `poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar`
  - `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar`
  - `commons-codec-1.9.jar`
  - `log4j-1.2.17.jar`

I can't even start doing the real stuff, since I can't even open the book! :(

When I saw the exception, I thought "Ok, let's get xmlbeans and see if it works", but xmlbeans is moved into Apache's attic.

Am I missing something? How can I open the workbook?

Comment: The Apache Attic means that a project isn't getting any further development. Everything there before still works though!

Comment: Also, you'll find all the jars you need (including xmlbeans) in the Apache POI binary download!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were right about needing `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` as well.  That appears to be one of Poi's dependencies.  I set up a vestigial Maven project with `poi`, `poi-scratchpad`, `poi-ooxml`, and `poi-ooxml-schemas` as my direct dependencies.  Maven yanked in these other JARs as dependencies:

- `commons-codec-1.9.jar`
- `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar`
- `stax-api-1.0.1.jar`

On further investigation, I see that `stax-api` is a transitive dependency for `xmlbeans`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm feeling kind of dumb now for not having found that myself, but... Anyway, I'm kinda surprised that POI relies on a library (xmlbeans) that's "archived" by Apache... hmmm... things are weird sometimes

Comment: @Barranka I'm glad if it helped.  I didn't know this about Poi either, until I happened to check what had been sucked into my local repo.  Maven tends to make this stuff transparent to me (perhaps too transparent sometimes).